# How can I move between words in the command prompt in tcsh in linux?

Tags: command-line, prompt, tcsh, line-editor

I want a feature like vim's going forward or backwards command `(w,e,ge,b)` etc in the shell prompt. I am using *tcsh* shell  in *Linux*. I would like to go *'n'* number of words backs or forward etc and do some editing(may be append or replace). How can I do that? It doesn't have to be the exact same commands as vim but how do I achieve the same results in the shell prompt?

Comment: `bindkey -v` to run in vi-mode...

Comment: @jasonwryan That should be an answer.

Comment: @jasonwryan how to come back to default mode which is *emacs* I suppose? I did go vi mode by using `bindkey -v` but unable to return to the default mode.

Answer (score 4):

By default shells are in emacs mode.

Pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> will send the cursor back one word on the command line. Pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will send the cursor forward.

Running `bindkey -v` will switch to vi mode. You'll need to press <kbd>esc</kbd> then vi commands will work. Running `bindkey -e` will switch to emacs mode.

Comment: for me `alt+b` or `alt+f` are not working in default(emacs mode). But `Escape+f` and `escape+b` are working fine.

Comment: `alt+f` is actually invoking gnome terminal's File menu.