# In tcsh shell how I find a particular word in the command prompt?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tcsh, line-editor

Suppose I have the following line in my command prompt and the cursor is at the and of the line or the beginning of the line by using (<kbd>CTRL+A</kbd>)

```
[subhrcho@slc04lyo pcbpel]$ abc def ghi jkl
```

How can I navigate to a particular word say, for example, to `def`. I am using *tcsh* shell in *linux* with default binding which I suppose is *emacs* mode.

P.S:I do not have a <kbd>Meta</kbd> key in my keyboard. I can move forward or backward between words  by using <kbd>CTRL+f</kbd> and  respectively. So I think my <kbd>Meta</kbd> key is the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. Please **correct me if that presumption is wrong**. <kbd>Alt</kbd> [isn't working either as the meta key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85388/how-can-i-move-between-words-in-the-command-prompt-in-tcsh-in-linux?rq=1#comment127249_85421).I had a look at [the emacs documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Word-Search.html) but invoking <kbd>CTRL-s w</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> is not working for me. It would just try to execute whatever is there in the prompt by first appending a `w` character to it and the prompt would say :

```
[subhrcho@slc04lyo pcbpel]$ abc def ghi jklw
abc: Command not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By <kbd>Meta-x</kbd> `tcsh` means that it expects the `ESC` ASCII character (aka `^[` or `\e`) followed by `x`. You can always do it by pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> and <kbd>x</kbd> quickly in sequence, or some terminals do it by pressing <kbd>Alt-x</kbd>.

Some other terminals send the character `x` with the 8th bit set when pressing <kbd>Alt-x</kbd>. With `xterm`, you can change that by adding:

```
XTerm*metaSendsEscape: true
```

to an X11 resource file.

Now, for searching in `tcsh`, if you want to emulate `emacs`/`zsh` <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd> in `emacs` mode, you'll have to bind the `i-search-back` and `i-search-fwd` widgets:

```
bindkey '^R' i-search-back
bindkey '^S' i-search-fwd
```

However note that generally, for the terminal driver, `^S` is the `stop` character that pauses the terminal input and output (resumed with `^Q`). So, if you want to bind `^S`, you'll have to disable that either by disabling flow control:

```
stty -ixon
```

Or bind `stop` to some other character:

```
stty stop '^T'
```

Comment: But `CTRL+R` also searches through the history command. I find it pretty useful and would like to retain that behavior. In that scenario if I do bindkey '^R' i-search-back, will the default behavior not get get overridden?

Comment: Also how can I make these bindings persist between sessions?

Comment: @Geek, `i-search-back` **is** to search through the history (starting with the current line). In the `tcsh` implementation I have access to, `^R` is bound to `redisplay`. Add those in `~/.tcshrc` to make persistent. Ever thought of running `man tcsh`?

Comment: Where can I find a list of available widgets? I tried `man bash` but there is no section for `bindkey`. Also I searched online and found this website: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxa500/tschbundkey.htm but there is no mention of `i-search-back` .

Comment: @Sergio, in `tcsh`, use `bindkey -l`. In `bash`, use `bind -l`

Comment: That worked thanks. One last question about readline  variables. In bash this will  display possible completions in different colors: `set color-stats on`. I tried the same in csh but did not work. How would I achieve this?. I asked complete question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437609/csh-bindkey-to-turn-on-readline-variable-visible-stats