# tcsh bindkey to turn on readline variable `visible-stats`

Tags: bash, shell, bind, tcsh

In `.inputrc` I store readline commands for `bash`, for example:

```
bind "\C-S": i-search-fwd
```

I do the same in `.bindings` for `tcsh`:

```
bindkey "^S" i-search-fwd
```

To specify readline variables in `.inputrc` I do:

```
set visible-stats on
```

However I haven't been able to do the same for `tcsh`. I have tried with `set` and `bindkey`.

So first question is, *how to specify readline variables for tcsh?*

Finally, is there a man page or man section for `bindkey`? For example I can find info for `bind` in `man bash`.

Answer (score 5):

`readline` is a library that is used by `bash` and some other software, but not by `tcsh`. For historical reasons, `tcsh` has its own implementation of readline-like functionality, whose feature set does not necessarily match one-for-one with readline's. So attempting to set readline variables for tcsh is fruitless, as the two have nothing to do with each other.

The closest equivalent of readline's `visible-stats` in `tcsh` is the shell variable `addsuffix`, and it should be already set by default.

tcsh's `bindkey` is a tcsh shell builtin, so you'll find it described in `man tcsh`, in the **Builtin commands** section. The `addsuffix` is also described in the same man page, in the **Special shell variables** section.

Comment: `addsuffix` is about adding the `/` after completing a directory in the inserted completion. `visible-stats` in `readline` is about adding `/`, `@`, `*`... suffixes to _displayed_ files. That's what `tcsh` does by default (upon `^D` or also upon TAB with `set autolist`) and AFAIK, there's no way to disable it. See also `set colors` to get the completion in color à la GNU `ls --color`

Comment: Note that `tcsh` line editor predates `bash`'s `readline` by a long time, and most of `readline`'s features are actually copied/inspired from `tcsh`

Comment: `set color` is the correct command for me (at least on tcsh 6.17.00 )